# Extend angular-selection-model to handle select via mouse drag

Tags: angularjs

I am using the directive angular-selection-model for creating selectable lists.

EDIT:

I have a selectable list generated by the code below:

[in codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNZeLy)

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jtrussell/angular-selection-model/master/dist/selection-model.js"></script>

<div ng-app="theApp" ng-controller="controller"> 
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="item in stuff track by $index" selection-model selection-model-mode="multiple-additive">
       {{item.label}} - {{item.selected}}
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myapp = angular.module('theApp', ['selectionModel']);

    myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {  
      $scope.stuff = [
            {selected: false, label: 'Scotchy scotch'},
            {selected: true, label: 'Monacle'},
            {selected: true, label: 'Curly mustache'},
            {selected: false, label: 'Top hat'}
      ];  
    });
```

I would like to be able to select multiple objects by mouse dragging - as in [this](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/) example. How do I enable this functionality?

Comment: can you post your code in plnkr?

Answer (score 3):

Here is some example for angular drag selection

Sorry for answer in only link but you may understand good enough than my explanation.

```
1) http://jsfiddle.net/few5E/

2) https://github.com/willgm/ngSelectable

3) https://github.com/jonotron/angular-selectable
```